# Issue of "Unsupported auth type for "Try this API" - api_key:apiKey." while working on google cloud endpoints with using Nodejs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, api-key

I created open API by using Nodejs and deploy on google cloud endpoints also trying to implement securing this API by using an API key.

Then, I created openapi.yaml file added security definition in the bottom that is :

```
# [START securityDef]
 securityDefinitions:
 # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
   type: "apiKey"
   name: "X-API-KEY"
   in: "query"
# [END securityDef]
```

And Under the path added security:

```
"/api/getProduct":
get:
  description: "Get product data."
  operationId: "getProduct"
  produces:
   - "application/json"
  responses:
   200:
    description: "getProduct"
    schema:
     $ref: "#/definitions/echoMessage"
  security:
  - api_key: []
```

After this, when I'm deploying the endpoint getting the message as shown in below image:

[image]

Now, I'm unable to understand what to do next?

Please, anyone can help me on the same. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your indentation is off in your api key example. Is that how it really looks?

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more, I didn't get you clearly.

Comment: The indentation in your top yaml example is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the same error message using the sample configuration provided in the [nodejs code samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/getting-started/openapi-appengine.yaml) by setting the `api_key.name` value to `X-API-KEY`, instead of `key`, like you did.

Apparently the Cloud Endpoints Portal requires it to be set to `key`, as once I switched back it worked as expected. Like the example below:

```
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
```